# Excel VBA copy and paste within loop

Tags: vba, excel

first post here.  Thanks for any help.  I have existing VBA Loop that runs through a list of names and creates a PDF with a "statement" of info specific to the employee (name).  I want to capture the info for each employee within the loop from Tab A, and paste it to another worksheet (same workbook, different tab) Tab B.  Please see image included.  I have also pasted my current loop.  Thanks very much for any  help.  I guess I need to insert some function or something before "Next" in my existing code.  Just not sure.  Sort of new at this.  Thanks again very much.
[image: Image Example of Excel Tabs]

```
Sub Loop_Through_List()

Dim cell                  As Excel.Range
Dim rgDV                  As Excel.Range
Dim DV_Cell               As Excel.Range

Set DV_Cell = Range("B4")

Set rgDV = Application.Range(Mid$(DV_Cell.Validation.Formula1, 2))
For Each cell In rgDV.Cells
    DV_Cell.Value = cell.Value
    Call PDFActiveSheet
Next
End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
Dim dlg                   As FileDialog
Set dlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
dlg.InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
dlg.Title = "Select folder to save PDFs"
If dlg.Show = -1 Then
    GetFolder = dlg.SelectedItems(1)
End If
End Function
```

Comment: What's your question? Does your current loop work, just need to tweak with something? Does it not work? etc...Can you please clarify?

Comment: Yes, current loop works fine.  just need to make it do something else as described in my initial post.

Comment: I did notice that I left a portion out of my code that I pasted above.  Thus, the Sub PDFActiveSheet is missing here.  Otherwise, current code is fine.  I just need some capability dropped in to existing code for the copy / paste  described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move data between worksheets, you can use something like this:

```
Dim TabA as Worksheet, TabB as Worksheet
Set TabA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tab A")
Set TabB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tab B")

TabB.Range("C2")=TabA.Range("I21").Value2
```

To address placing the total in the right row, you could use the .Find method:

```
Dim SearchText as String
Dim datarow as Long
SearchText=TabA.Range("B4")
datarow = TabB.Cells.Find(What:SearchText, After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, searchorder:xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlNext).Row
TabB.Cells(datarow, 3)=TabA.Range("I21").Value2
```

You can expand upon the above to also dynamically select the column.

Comment: Thanks, this is very good help.  I am able to operate as you note to dynamically select the proper row to place data.  I am in the process of trying to figure out  / replicate for the dynamic selection of both row and column based on your code.  This will help me learn.  I will post progress here and or ask for added assistance.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Glad I could help. I'm still very much a VBA newbie myself and have learned a lot on stackoverflow.  My first instinct to match the quarter would be to use `.Find` to search for `TabA.Range("B2")`.  You could use most of the same command in my answer, but change searchorder to `xlByRows`

Comment: Thanks again.  I put in the expansion to select the columns and it worked great.  Just like I was asking.  Thanks again for your assistance.